# Running Windows games on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

I'm considering buying either a Xbox One or a PS4 for playing next season's games (like FIFA 2016). However I'd also like to buy a new computer to play Windows games (like Blizzard's new game: Heroes of the Storm). Unfortunately I don't have money for both things. Hence the following question:

Is it possible to install Windows on Xbox One, connect a keyboard/mouse, and play on it normal windows games, as if the Xbox One was just a PC? If not, why?

Comment: The downvotes are a bit harsh - it may be obvious to some but it's not a bad question.

Comment: @Alex, down-votes aren't "harsh", they're part of a mechanism to teach users how to ask a good question. The down-vote tool tip says *"This question **does not show research effort**; it is unclear or not useful"*. Down-votes are only a constructive teaching tool, just as much as up-votes.

Comment: @Ben I know what they're for - and I had a look for the same information online to check if it's easy to find. I couldn't find much. Agreed that the OP could have mentioned this, though.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. The normal Windows OS is not compatible with the Xbox One.

I found a pretty [nice explanation:](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2023659/xbox-full.html)

> Windows can't install to the XB1, or the PS4 because it uses a SHARED MEMORY hardware setup that is not compatible.

One would need to rewrite a Windows OS to make it compatible with the Xbox One and then also find a way to install it without bricking the console.

Answer (score -1):

Get the xbox and get a gaming PC that comes with a free upgrade to Win 10, when it comes out on July 29 2015. By the end of the year the XB1 will be getting an OS ugrade that be the Win 10 basic design, and will even work with your PC.

You will be able to stream your XB games to your PC, along with a lot of other cool things. There will even be a program that will allow streaming to Mac's, for those poor souls ;-)

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking for - he cannot afford to buy *more than one console*, so he was wanting to know *if he could use his console **as** a PC*